# iOS: Delete file in .DocumentDirectory using Swift2

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, delete-file

I have a project I'm working on that saves data to a PDF.  The code for this is:

```
// Save PDF Data

let recipeItemName = nameTextField.text

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

pdfData.writeToFile("\(documentsPath)/\(recipeFileName).pdf", atomically: true)
```

I'm able to view the files in a separate `UITableView` I have in another `ViewController`.  When the user swipes the `UITableViewCell` I want it to also delete the item from the `.DocumentDirectory`.  My code for the `UITableView` delete is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source

        savedPDFFiles.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

        // Delete actual row

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)


        // Deletion code for deleting from .DocumentDirectory here???


    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view

    }

}
```

I've tried finding the answer online but can't find anything for Swift 2.  Can someone please help?

I've tried working with this but with no luck:

```
var fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var error:NSErrorPointer = NSErrorPointer()
fileManager.removeItemAtPath(filePath, error: error)
```

I just want to remove the particular item swiped and not all data in the `DocumentDirectory`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`removeItemAtPath:error:` is the Objective-C version. For swift, you want `removeItemAtPath`, like this:

```
    do {
       try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(path)
    } catch {}
```

In swift, this is a pretty common pattern when working with methods that will `throw` - prefix the call with `try` and enclose in `do-catch`. You will be doing less with error pointers then you would in objective-c.  Instead, the errors need to be caught or, as in the snippet above, ignored. To catch and handle the error, you could do your delete like this:

```
    do {
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let documentDirectoryURLs = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

        if let filePath = documentDirectoryURLs.first?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.pdf").path {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(filePath)
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate it.  I adjusted it a little to work with my project.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to retrieve the `recipeFileName` from the edited cell to reconstruct the file path.

It is unclear as to how you are populating your `UITableViewCell` data, so I will cover the most common scenario.

Assume you have an array of files that you use to populate the `dataSource`.

```
let recipeFiles = [RecipeFile]()
```

with the `RecipeFile` struct

```
struct RecipeFile {
   var name: String
}
```

In `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, you probably set the recipeFile like so :

```
cell.recipeFile = recipeFiles[indexPath.row]
```

so in `tableView(_:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:)`, you can retrieve the file name like this:

```
let recipeFile = recipeFiles[indexPath.row]
```

and delete your file

```
var fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(recipeFile.name).pdf"
do {
    fileManager.removeItemAtPath(filePath, error: error)
} catch _ {
    //catch any errors
}
```